# Access AngularJS variable with Java Selenium JavascriptExecutor

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, selenium

Here is a div with an AngularJS ng-click attribute that sets a variable when the div is clicked.

```
<div id="id"
     ng-click="foo.bar = true;">
     Set bar variable on foo object to true
</div>
```

Here is some Java code that uses Selenium to click on the div element.

```
By upload = By.id("id");
driver.findElement(uploadCensus).click();
```

When I run the Java code, the AngularJS hangs for eternity. I figure foo.bar is not set when the div is clicked so here is some code that sets the variable directly.

```
By upload = By.id("id");
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
    .executeScript("foo.bar = true;",   
    driver.findElement(upload));
```

Stacktrace

> unknown error: foo is not defined (Session info: chrome=56.0.2924.87)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.25.426923
>   (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information) Command duration or timeout: 51 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15
>   17:00:58' System info: host: 'WV-VC104-027', ip: '{ip}', os.name:
>   'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_151' Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false,
>   mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false,
>   chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.25.426923
>   (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed),
>   userDataDir=C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir5600_4225},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal,
>   databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false,
>   version=56.0.2924.87, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}] Session ID:
>   a7734312eff62fe452a53895b221a58d

When I try to set `foo.bar` I cannot get a reference to the variable because it is not globally defined and is buried somewhere inside AngularJS source code.  I have tried to unminify the index and look for the variable but I cannot seem to find it.  I want to manually set the `foo.bar` variable through the `JavascriptExecutor` but cannot get a reference to the variable.  How would I find then set the variable?

If that seems like the wrong way to trigger this `ng-click`, I am open to ideas.  I am sure Protractor has a way to handle this but this AngularJS application deployed in an enterprise environment and have been trying to get the business side to approve the tech for months.  I am stuck with Selenium.  Help...

Comment: What is the error when you're using the `JS` executor?

Comment: @demouser123 editted; lol i forgot the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Just answer for your questions directly [ Dont use it for your case :) ]**

Angular have isolated variable scope.So you need get the scope and the set the variable in it.

```
angular.element("#id").scope().foo.bar = true;
```

But dont use it for your case. As you are testing the application at system level, you have to test them in same as user does.

**Recommended Answer: Wait for angular testablity in java**

Whatever protractor can handle, your java test can also do. Both are wrappers over the selenium bindings. Ultimately all the selenese code executes in the same browser you test.

`waitForAngularMethod` is most inevitable method that your missing in your test. Good thing is you can execute same kind of javascript using JavaScriptExecutor inside expilcit wait.

*If you are javascript lover, you can refer the [waitForangular](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/5.1.2/lib/clientsidescripts.js#L135) method implementation in protractor. It is just a simple validation check and wait using callback.*

Your java code for creating expected condrion for waitforangular

```
String waitForAngularJs ="Your javascript goes here"; // as it is lengthy read it from file and store here.
ExpectedCondition<Boolean> waitForAngular= new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
                return ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(waitForAngularJs).equals(true);
            }
};

 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
 wait.until(waitForAngular);
```

**Wait for angular Javascript (Modified for your Java execution. But I didn't check it):**

The method requires two attributes, root locator hook and a call back. I have set callback as a simple funtion return true and hooks with root locator which is `[ng-app]`.

```
var testCallback = function() {
  return true;
 };

    // Wait for angular1 testability first and run waitForAngular2 as a callback
    var waitForAngular1 = function(callback) {

      if (window.angular) {
        var hooks = window.angular.element('[ng-app]');
        if (!hooks){
          callback();  // not an angular1 app
        }
        else{
          if (hooks.$$testability) {
            hooks.$$testability.whenStable(callback);
          } else if (hooks.$injector) {
            hooks.$injector.get('$browser')
                .notifyWhenNoOutstandingRequests(callback);
          } else if (!rootSelector) {
            throw new Error(
                'Could not automatically find injector on page: "' +
                window.location.toString() + '".  Consider using config.rootEl');
          } else {
            throw new Error(
                'root element (' + rootSelector + ') has no injector.' +
                ' this may mean it is not inside ng-app.');
          }
        }
      }
      else {callback();}  // not an angular1 app
    };

    // Wait for Angular2 testability and then run test callback
    var waitForAngular2 = function() {
      if (window.getAngularTestability) {
        if (rootSelector) {
          var testability = null;
          var el = document.querySelector(rootSelector);
          try{
            testability = window.getAngularTestability(el);
          }
          catch(e){}
          if (testability) {
            testability.whenStable(testCallback);
            return;
          }
        }

        // Didn't specify root element or testability could not be found
        // by rootSelector. This may happen in a hybrid app, which could have
        // more than one root.
        var testabilities = window.getAllAngularTestabilities();
        var count = testabilities.length;

        // No angular2 testability, this happens when
        // going to a hybrid page and going back to a pure angular1 page
        if (count === 0) {
          testCallback();
          return;
        }

        var decrement = function() {
          count--;
          if (count === 0) {
            testCallback();
          }
        };
        testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {
          testability.whenStable(decrement);
        });

      }
      else {testCallback();}  // not an angular2 app
    };

    if (!(window.angular) && !(window.getAngularTestability)) {
      // no testability hook
      throw new Error(
          'both angularJS testability and angular testability are undefined.' +
          '  This could be either ' +
          'because this is a non-angular page or because your test involves ' +
          'client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor\'s ' +
          'bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details');
    } else {waitForAngular1(waitForAngular2);}  // Wait for angular1 and angular2
// Testability hooks sequentially
```

**Why we need wait for angular and logic behind**

Why we need this because the angular uses html templating, two way data binding, ajax requests and routing. So after a page navigation, we have to wait all this operation (requests & promises) to complete. Else the html will not respond as expected as in your case.

**Check the angular testablity**

i.e. to check the testablity of angular. For this angular itselfs provide a method.

To check based on a element,

```
 window.getAngularTestability(el).whenStable(callback); //Here el is element to be valiated.
```

To check all testablities,

```
 window.getAllAngularTestabilities();
   testabilities.forEach(function(testability) {
        testability.whenStable(callback);
});
```

**Wait for all http pending request to complete**

Before checking the angular testablity, we can make sure there is no  http request pending with the following lines.

```
angular.element(document).injector().get('$http').pendingRequest.length
```